# Как высчитывать разницу во времени, учитывая часовые зоны?

Tags: javascript, время, timezone, momentjs

Мне нужно сделать таймер обратного отсчета до какого-то события при помощи библиотеки MomentJS.

Сервер мне присылает время (назовем его `eventTime`), до которого должен идти отсчет, я выясняю разницу между текущим и вывожу в HTML. Здесь все просто. 
Проблема в том, что сервер присылает время по МСК и преобразование `eventTime = moment.utc(time)` в функции таймера мне ничего не дает.

Как мне высчитывать разницу во времени, учитывая часовые зоны?

Comment: Правильнее заставить сервер присылать время в utc или unix timestamp

Comment: А если сервер не заставляется? :) 
У меня на самом деле возникла мысль всегда отнимать три часа из приходящего времени. Но, сдается мне, это костыль.

Comment: Вот потому что три часа никто не гарантирует (кто знает что нашей думе взбредёт в голову) нужно не костылить, сделать по нормальному. А если уж костылить, то взять moment tz и не забывать обновлять базу таймзон

Comment: Пинайте бэкендеров, чтобы отправлять время с сервера в UTC.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В идеале конечно получать от сервера время в UTC. Но если это невозможно, преобразовывайте из московского времени с помощью [moment timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/):

```
var t = moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", 'Europe/Moscow');
```

И не забывайте обновлять библиотеку `moment timezone` каждый раз, когда вступит в силу новый закон о летнем времени в зоне 'Europe/Moscow' (и ребята из `moment timezone` обновят сборку).

Альтернативный вариант - присылать с сервера сразу оставшееся время (например в секундах) до нужного события. В этом случае будет не важно, какое время у клиента (в том числе, если оно вообще неправильно выставлено, как иногда бывает когда пытаются продлить триальные версии некоторых программ).